# Interference between Jquery-UI and Colorbox (first image caption title in colorbox not shown)

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui, colorbox, title

I have got an interference problem between jquery ui tooltips and colorbox. when i click on a image of an image gallery, colorbox opens but the image´s (title) caption is hidden. when i click (within colorbox view) on the next or previous image of the gallery the caption of that image is shown as expected. here is the js code i tried to prevent this (via „close“):

```
<script>
$(function() {
    $( document ).tooltip({ track: true })  
    $('#SGWG *[title]').tooltip("close");   
});
</script>
```

and here is the image´s HTML code (they are in a table):

```
<td>

<a class="SGWG" href="images/sgwg4.jpg" title="So Gut Wie Genug <font color='#333'>|</font> <font color='#444'>30.5.-16.6.2012 Ballhaus Ost</font>">

<img name="sgwg1_r3_c1" title="So Gut Wie Genug" alt="So Gut Wie Genug" src="sgwg1_r3_c1.jpg" width="400" height="300" border="0" id="sgwg1_r3_c1" title="So Gut Wie Genug" alt="So Gut Wie Genug"></a>

</td>
```

but … it does not work. I also tried  `$('#SGWG *[title]').tooltip("close");`   and `$('.SGWG *[title]').tooltip("close");`  but they both didnt work …

what´s wrong?

bc

Comment: Welcome to SO!  Would you be able to set up a sample of this problem on jsfiddle.net so that we can see exactly what you mean?

Comment: I tried but it did not work as the result window is too small to show the effect of the missing caption in the color box window.
The problem is: when clicking on the image, colorbox opens and the first title (=caption) is not shown.

Comment: i put a demonstration file here: http://www.moritzmajcesanman.com/sogutwiegenug/tooltip.html

Comment: i tried qtip2 instead of query ui tooltips but the same problem: no caption on the first color box image. so color box is the problem …